# Integration by substitution in double integral: Is the following correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

I have the follwing for a one-dimensional integral:
$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-az)g(z)dz$$ where f() and g() are functions. Using $u = G(z)$, $G'(z) = g(z), G(-\infty)=0, G(\infty)=1$
I get: $$I = \int_{0}^{1}f(x-aG^{-1}(u))du$$ which I can evaluate. I know this first part is correct. **Now what about the follwowing, will this be correct or am I missing something?**
$$ J = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-az_1-bz_2)g_1(z_1)g_2(z_2)dz_1 dz_2 $$
$$ = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x-aG_1^{-1}(u_1)-bG_2^{-1}(u_2))du_1 du_2$$
The same as above applies: $u_i = G_i(z_i)$, $G_i'(z_i) = g_i(z_i), G_i(-\infty)=0, G_i(\infty)=1$ for $i=1,2$

Comment: Provided $G_i$ is continuous and invertible, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Yes that will be fulfilled. So no need for a cross derivative or something?

Comment: Cross derivative? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that term. You can use the one-dimensional substitution exactly as in the previous case. More generally, there's the theorem on change of variables that says the integral differential changes according to the determinant of the differential of the change of variables. In your case, the differential of the change is a diagonal matrix, so the end result should be the same as applying the 'naïve' one-dimensional substituion, as you first did.

Comment: Even though you didn't know about corss derivative you answered the question by: 'the differential of the change is a diagonal matrix'. That's what I had in mind. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped.